# Checking Minimagick height freezes console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file, upload, minimagick

I'm using Rails with MiniMagick and have this obj that I've uploaded through `file_field` and `MiniMagick::Image.read(image.read)`:

```
=> #<MiniMagick::Image:0x007feb61ac7048
 @info=#<MiniMagick::Image::Info:0x007feb61ac6ff8 @info={}, @path="/var/folders/s5/0r70nfzn2cj74qmc90ry3kc80000gp/T/mini_magick20170608-62480-1kxoub0">,
 @path="/var/folders/s5/0r70nfzn2cj74qmc90ry3kc80000gp/T/mini_magick20170608-62480-1kxoub0",
 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/s5/0r70nfzn2cj74qmc90ry3kc80000gp/T/mini_magick20170608-62480-1kxoub0 (closed)>>
```

I want to look into the object's height with `image['height']` but whenever I've done that my command line freezes or I get `No live threads left. Deadlock?`. If I just let the program run without the debugger I get

```
`identify -format %m %w %h %b /var/folders/s5/0r70nfzn2cj74qmc90ry3kc80000gp/T/mini_magick20170608-62480-v5agnm[0]` failed with error: identify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
```

I've tried adding in

```
MiniMagick.configure do |config|
  config.validate_on_create = false
  config.validate_on_write = false
end
```

But it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your image path, For troubleshooting take RMagick out of the equation and just test find
the file with:

```
myfile = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/images/world.jpg"
  File.open myfile, 'r' { |f| puts "Success!\n\nFile Contents:" + f.read
}
```

Also, try using "script/console" to play with this.  The above lines
can be typed in there.  It will make it easier to experiment without
crashing the web server.

for your [reference](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/79994)

Comment: @stackjlei if you satisfy with my answer then make it correct and vote up